# PhpStorm going mad highlighting JS syntax

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

My PhpStorm installation is highlighting my JS files for syntax (`JSLint`). It is not recognizing functions in other JS files within the project. The PHP side is OK.

```
JSHint: 'result' is not defined W110
JSLINT: Expected "" and instead found ""
```

Those are some of the errors I am seeing. How do I reset the JS syntax checker to default?

Comment: I would suggest asking this on customer support forum. At least all my questions were answered there in a matter of hour or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like your code being linted with JSHint/JSLint, please try disabling them in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools`: clear `Enable` checkboxes in JSLint and JSHint pages.
Otherwise, you have to change linters configuration to match your setup: add 'result'and other global vars to 'Predefined' in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint, 'Predefined (,separated)'`, etc